# *Some* figure captions from RMarkdown not showing

Tags: rstudio, knitr, pandoc, r-markdown

Essentially, I have a Rmd document configured like this:

```
---
title: "Example"
author: "me"
date: "December 2014"
output:
  pdf_document:
    fig_caption: yes
    keep_tex: yes
--
```

Then, in the document, I use `ggplot2` to show some charts, for example:

````
```{r myLabel, fig.cap='My Caption'}
qplot(1:10, 10:1)
```
````

Now, for some reason I cannot explain or investigate any deeper than this, the produced TeX does not contain the figure environment, even if I force it with `fig.env='figure'`. Instead, the TeX only has the `includegraphics` command:

```
\includegraphics{journal_files/figure-latex/myLabel-1.pdf}
```

Other figures in the same document do have the figure environment, with the caption. I.e., the TeX output "Knit PDF" *should* be producing is:

```
\begin{figure}[htbp]
\centering
\includegraphics{journal_files/figure-latex/myLabel-1.pdf}
\caption{My Citation}
\end{figure}
```

The R Markdown log window only shows irrelevant stuff:

```
label: myLabel (with options) 
List of 2
 $ fig.cap: chr "My Caption"
 $ fig.env: chr "figure"

cropping journal_files/figure-latex/myLabel-1.pdf
PDFCROP 1.38, 2012/11/02 - Copyright (c) 2002-2012 by Heiko Oberdiek.
```

How do I either

- find out what exactly is going on (debug log?) once I press "Knit PDF" and get to the TeX (the "R Markdown" output window shows no errors, and even echos the [missing] captions!),
- or, even better, has anybody had this very problem and knows what is wrong with RStudio, knitr, and pandoc?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Turns out, the solution is quite simple: the RMarkdown compiler does not show captions for two consecutive figures, like this:

````
```{r myLabel1, fig.cap='My Caption 1'}
qplot(1:10, 10:1)
```
```{r myLabel2, fig.cap='My Caption 2'}
qplot(1:10, 10:1)
```
````

or for a figure not separated from the text in a new paragraph like this:

````
```{r myLabel1, fig.cap='My Caption 1'}
qplot(1:10, 10:1)
```
As shown in Fig. 2, the inter-galactic distances are strongly correlated with the observed redshift ...
````

In this setting, the captions are missing and no figure environment is created in the TeX file.

Instead, between the two plots, there **must** be at least **two** *spacing* (newline) characters. I.e., this works nicely and both captions show:

````
```{r myLabel1, fig.cap='My Caption 1'}
qplot(1:10, 10:1)
```

```{r myLabel2, fig.cap='My Caption 2'}
qplot(1:10, 10:1)
```
````

Even though this is a feature to make it possible to include inline graphics, it would be nice if there was a warning message for figures with a fig.cap argument that does not show up.

Comment: That is documented in the Pandoc documentation: http://johnmacfarlane.net/pandoc/README.html#images It is not an _error_ (but a _choice_ you want to make instead), so rmarkdown cannot really do much about it.

Comment: Well, I am not able to deduce this problem from the linked information or any other place. Plus, I think, the "compiler" output should have at least presented a warning that putting triple-backticks on the beginnings of two consecutive lines is something that will not be handled correctly.

Comment: The documentation says "An image occurring **by itself in a paragraph** will be rendered as a figure with a caption", and **a paragraph** means a newline.